# How can i make this top right curved div in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am having little difficulty in coming up with css for the following div, I have tried using **border-radius** and tried get my hands dirty with **psuedo elements** but I am kinda stuck.

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-top-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;

 .childBox {
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     position: relative;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div class="childBox">
       <img/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Please show us your attempts !

Comment: Investigate clip-path maybe.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to try with an SVG image.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: You added one CSS rule. We need to see a [mcve]

Comment: Added entire code, apologies it's been a while I used SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some gradient can help you

```css
.box {
  width: 40px;
  padding-left:40px;
  height: 40px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box,
    radial-gradient(50% 100% at bottom left,#0000 97%,white) 0 0   /40px 50%,
    radial-gradient(50% 100% at top right  ,white 97%,#0000) 0 100%/40px 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Change the colors to understand the puzzle:

```css
.box {
  width: 40px;
  padding-left:40px;
  height: 40px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(black 0 0) content-box,
    radial-gradient(50% 100% at bottom left,red 97%,blue) 0 0   /40px 50%,
    radial-gradient(50% 100% at top right  ,green 97%,pink) 0 100%/40px 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```